# NFC tag and php

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am new to NFC tags and am interested on how it work. I have bought a NFC tag and am able to write studentid to the tag. Now my problem is how to pass the student id to a php web service and check if this student has paid his/her meals before thy can proceed to the cafeteria when thy scan their student cards through my application.

Kindly anyone assist me on how i can do this. below is what i have done.

```
//reading the tag
private String readText(NdefRecord record) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        byte[] payload = record.getPayload();

        // Get the Text Encoding
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";

        // Get the Language Code
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;

        // Get the Text
        return new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
        //show the student id in a textedit
            mTextView.setText(result);

            //pass variable to the server and get contents. I want to pass the student id to the method
            getstudentinfo(result);
        }
    }

      void getstudentinfo(String studID) {

        //get connection to the server using http request
        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        httppost= new HttpPost("http://myip/getStudentBl.php?studID="+ studID);

        try{

        response = getThreadSafeClient().execute(httppost);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        //checking the response and info the user
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            dialog.dismiss();
            }
            });

        //if the user is found
        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Student Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Saved Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                stdBalance.setText("Student Balance " + response);
            }
            });
            //show the dashboard screen
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("No Record")){
            //show error results
            showAlert();
        }
        //end try catch
        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            }

    }
```

Comment: So, how should the code work, and what it the problem with your code, or what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, with android readers at a minimum, if the tag holds an URL, it will automatically load the browser and go to the URL (no asking if you want to open the app nor if you want to go to the URL). You should be able to just put the student_id as a query string and use it in a page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks here to have an exemple of an NDEF implementation : [Github repo](https://github.com/julien14/AndroidNdefImplementation/tree/master/NfcNDEFReader/src/fr/oversimple/nfc/ndefReader)

In the main activity you will have to modify the

```
@Override
    public void ndefDataRead(String ndefData) {
    demoTextView.setText(ndefData);
}
```

to call your  getstudentinfo(String studID) methods and it might work